# looking up that the user press a key or not?

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to look-up that whether a user's pressed a keyboard key.
I tried some code:

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Int32 vKey);
    .....
     if ((GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F10) == -32767))
       {....}
```

What it does is that it just check the pressing of F10 key.It doesn't care whether it is Shift+F10 or Ctrl+F10 or F10.
But what i wanted is that to look-up them separately say if it is Shift+F10 then tell me the user pressed Shift+F10,if it is F10 then tell me the user pressed F10.
How can i get there a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

cant you check as below?

```
//in pseudocode
if (f10pressed) {
    if (shiftpressed) {
        //Shift+F10
    } else if (ctrlpressed) {
        //Ctrl+F10
    } else {
        //F10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple way; GetAsyncKeyState() will return you the value of the exact key you specified, ignoring concepts of modifier keys. Handling [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handles some modifiers you want but for all of them (shift, alt, ctrl) you have to explicitly check other keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `GetAsyncKeyState` for each key you're interested in.  In this case you will check for F10 and then check for shift, ctrl, alt and others.  See [virtual key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the possible values and see [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
short key = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F10);
// Check the most significant bit to see if the key is down
if ( ( key & 0x8000 ) > 0 )
{
     // Check  shift is down 0x10 is value for VK_SHIFT
     key = GetAsyncKeyState( 0x10 );
     if ( key & 0x8000 ) > 0 )
     {
         // Shift key is down as well
     }
     // Repeat for other key states.
}
```

Looking at the c# [keys enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) there are number of possible values for shift, you might need to experiment a bit.